# Gaussian curvature/Euler characteristic of Facebook clusters

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-complexes, data-analysis

If I look at a connected subgraph on a small collection of actors (such as a small cluster) in the Facebook social network, and I find that

1) The Euler characteristic of the clique complex built on this subgraph is strictly positive, no matter what subgraph I choose,

..then via the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, since a finite simplicial complex is compact, the total Gaussian curvature of any complex in the facebook graph is strictly positive.

**Does this imply something**, e.g. about embedding this subgraph in a metric space?

I notice, for example, that the random Vietoris-Rips complex also has connected subgraphs with expected positive Euler characteristic.

Is it quite straightforward for highly clustered graphs to show this positive Euler characteristic property?